# Regex replace templates path amber with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I need replace all \ for / in paths in this format:

```
util.RenderTemplate(w, "auth\\profile", c)
util.RenderTemplate(w, "auth\\something\\extra", c)
```

The path can have at max three levels with two delimiters,
but I would like to write something generic for n levels, n-1 delimiters.

I come with this simple sed query
`sed -n -E "s:(util.RenderTemplate\(w,.+)\\\(.+, c\)):\1/\2:p" file`
but this let me in

```
util.RenderTemplate(w, "auth\/profile", c)
util.RenderTemplate(w, "auth\\something\/extra", c)
```

So it works only one 2 levels path and not replacing properly because it left \ from capturing group.

I have modified sed query like this:

`sed -n -E 's:(util.RenderTemplate\(w,[^\]+)\\\\([^\]+, c\)):\1/\2:p' file`

```
util.RenderTemplate(w, "auth/profile", c)
THIS EVEN DID NOT FOUND util.RenderTemplate(w, "auth\\something\\extra", c)
```

I am close to solution with negating group [^] it didn't carry extra \
from capturing group but it doesnt work when in path is multiple \ delimiters...
Can somebody help me with universal solution and explanation?

I am expecting to find and replace even multi levels paths
So this

```
util.RenderTemplate(w, "auth\\something\\extra", c)
```

substitutes to

```
util.RenderTemplate(w, "auth/something/extra", c)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I added my expectation, need to replace all \\ for / even in paths like A\\B\\C\\D not only single delimited A\\B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed '/util\.RenderTemplate/s~\\\\~/~g' file

util.RenderTemplate(w, "auth/something/extra", c)
```

This `awk` should also work

```
awk -F '\\\\\\\\' -v OFS=/ '/util\.RenderTemplate/ {$1=$1} 1' file
```

Comment: It seems working but it replaces also path outside util.RenderTemplate, it can be fixed because there are only 2 places but I would like to substitute only in util.RenderTemplate(w, "A\\B\\C", c) where substitution occurs in string "A\\B\\C"

Comment: Can you try: `sed '/util\.RenderTemplate/s~\\\\~/~g' file`

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`'s global substitution function you could try following too.

```
awk '/util\.RenderTemplate/{gsub(/\\\\/,"/")} 1' Input_file
```

***Logical explanation:*** Using `gsub`(global substitution) to substitute `\\`(where I am escaping `\` to make it like `\\` so it becomes `\\\\` for 2 times `\\` so that `awk` treats `\` as literal character) with `/` all of its occurrences. `1` will print the current edited/non-edited lines.